# Cordova android: exit from app when close inappbrowser

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to exit out of my application (without alert) when the inappbrowser closes. I'm trying to do so by adding a eventlistener to the browser. But it's not working.

this is my code:

```
    function redirectTo(location) {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
    //showPleasewait('Redirecting','Please wait');
    var d = setInterval(function () {
        window.open(location, '_blank',
            'location=no,zoom=no,toolbar=no,fullscreen=no');
            clearInterval(d);}, 6000);
}  

var app = {
        // Application Constructor
        initialize: function () {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready',
                this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
        },
        // deviceready Event Handler
        //
        // Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
        // 'pause', 'resume', etc.
        onDeviceReady: function () {
            this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        },
        // Update DOM on a Received Event
        receivedEvent: function (id) {
            if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
                navigator.notification.alert('An internet connection is required to continue ');
                }
                else {
                    redirectTo("example.com");
                    //Replce URL with your website URL
                }
            }
        };
        app.initialize();
```

I try add this:

```
ref.addEventListener('exit', exitCallback);
        function exitCallback() {
        navigator.app.exitApp();}
```

but don't work.

Does somebody know why? Also if you have a better idea on how to exit the app when the inappbrowser closes, please help me.

I'm using cordova for andorid.
Thanks in advance.